# Query to find Hold Times for multiple holds

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am writing a query to get changed timestamp by record ID and the time it remained in the same status.
So if the table is

Sample :

| id | Status | OperationTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Hold | 2022-04-12 00:00:00 |
| B | Available | 2022-04-13 00:00:00 |
| C | Hold | 2022-04-14 00:00:00 |
| D | Hold | 2022-04-13 00:00:00 |
| A | QA | 2022-04-12 06:00:00 |
| C | QA | 2022-04-14 08:00:00 |
| A | Hold | 2022-04-13 02:00:00 |
| E | Available | 2022-04-15 00:00:00 |
| A | Available | 2022-04-16 00:00:00 |
| D | Available | 2022-04-17 00:00:00 |

Output:

| id | Hold Time | Change Time | Change Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-04-12 00:00:00 | 2022-04-12 06:00:00 | QA |
| A | 2022-04-13 02:00:00 | 2022-04-16 00:00:00 | Available |
| C | 2022-04-14 00:00:00 | 2022-04-14 08:00:00 | QA |
| D | 2022-04-13 00:00:00 | 2022-04-13 02:00:00 | Available |

Basically, I need to track when a record gets put on hold and the first instance that it comes off hold.

By using this query-

```
select id, hold_time, min(case when OperationTS> Hold_Time then OperationTS END) as Change_Time, Status as Change_Value
from Sample JOIN (
select id, OperationTS as Hold_Time
from Sample
where status='Hold'
Group By id) S2 USING (id)
where status <> 'Hold'
group by id,status
```

I get

| id | Hold Time | Change Time | Change Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-04-12 00:00:00 | 2022-04-16 00:00:00 | Available |
| A | 2022-04-12 00:00:00 | 2022-04-12 06:00:00 | QA |
| A | 2022-04-13 02:00:00 | 2022-04-16 00:00:00 | Available |
| C | 2022-04-14 00:00:00 | 2022-04-14 08:00:00 | QA |
| D | 2022-04-13 00:00:00 | 2022-04-13 02:00:00 | Available |

So I am getting an incorrect row which matches the first Hold time to the Last Change time. I realized that this will happen as the number of holds increase. Is there a way to match the first hold time to first QA/ Available and then "reset" so the next Hold only matches to the next status change?

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using sql server <> mysql

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: Are you sure? That join syntax looks like mysql and is not valid in sql server.

Comment: Strange, I use bigQuery. I will change to mySql then. Thank you

Comment: You should probably tag this with BigQuery then. BigQuery<>MySQL<>SQL Server. They are all different things.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `LEAD` for this.

Something like:

```
SELECT id, holdtime, nexttime, nextstatus
FROM
 (SELECT id, 
  status, 
  operationts holdtime, 
  LEAD(status) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY operationts) nextstatus,
  LEAD(operationts) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY operationts) nexttime
  FROM sample) a
WHERE status='Hold'
```

`LEAD(status) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY operationts)` means "find the next `status`, ordering by `operationts`, that has the same `id`"

Edited to add: I [tested this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3c6a5da2cceaa4aa6d621d21825cc5d5) against SQL Server since that's what this was originally tagged with, but no matter what you're using, most modern DBMSes will let you use `LEAD`.